# At some point for a mobile browser the desktop version will be returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a site that runs on ASP.NET MVC4 RC1. Depending on the client it renders index.aspx or index.mobile.aspx.

This works smoothely until some point in time when for some pages the desktop version is rendered. Even setting a cookie .ASPXbrowseroverride which usually forces the mobile view to be rendered still renders the desktop version.
The behaviour can be resetted to normal by restarting the app / touching web.config.

This all looks like some issue with caching or static variables in the implementation of the mobile feature in ASP.NET MVC4. Is there anything I can do about it?

We use fiftyoneMobile, but the issue is the same when we dont use it.

We dont have OutputCache enabled and use Webforms viewengine.

Comment: This has been fixed. See http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes

Comment: Great news! I have to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is known, ist a Bug in MVC4 RC. Here u can find a description of the issue and a answer how to workaround this bug.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1824033.aspx/2/10?MVC+4+RC+Mobile+View+Cache+bug+

Here the link to the work item at codeplex:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/280

Greetz